# Custom status bar above UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm adding in a custom 20px 'status bar' above a UINavigationBar. The status bar will show a 'Refreshing...' label when the user pulls to refresh. In normal operation, the default status bar will show, then I call `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:` to fade out the default status bar and reveal the custom status bar behind it.

My issue is that when I hide the default status bar, the navigation bar moves up 20px and overlaps the custom status bar!

Is there any way to force the UINavigationBar to stay in the same spot?

Comment: Yes, but it will require managing the navigationBar or viewController yourself somehow. Another option that some use, instead of hiding the statusBar, create a new UIWindow above it with your overlay. This may be a smoother option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! So the solution (as Ryan suggested) was create a UIWindow and set:

```
self.overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
```

This creates a a window that sits above the status bar. I didn't realize that you could have multiple UIWindows showing at any one time. This is an incredibly elegent solution.

Some gotchas:

- Set `self.overlayWindow.hidden = NO`. New windows are hidden by default.
- You **do not** need to set a root view controller for the new window.
- You **do not** need to call `makeKeyAndVisible`... Setting `self.overlayWindow.hidden = NO` is enough.
- You can add `UIView` subviews directly to the `UIWindow`.
- You must keep a strong reference to `self.overlayWindow`. If it gets released, the `UIWindow` will disappear (since it's not added as a subview or retained anywhere else):

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *overlayWindow;
  ```
- Adapting for rotation might take a bit of extra work.

I had a bit of fun and created a class that subclassed `UIWindow` and encapsulated the setup. In Swift:

```
class StatusBarOverlay: UIWindow {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
        self.hidden = false
        self.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```